# Understanding HTML5 addColorStop() method offset parameter

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm learning HTML5 Canvas Gradient. I understood that `createLinearGradient(x,y,x1,y1)` creates a linear gradient starting from (x,y) to (x1,y1). But from [what I have read](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_gradients.asp), there is a `addColorStop()` that specifies the color stops, and its position along the gradient. So this method takes two parameters, the color, which is straightforward and I understood, but the other parameter, the gradient position, which takes the value between 0 and 1, is what I don't understand. What does 0 specify? What does 1 specify? I searched on the web, but couldn't find anything I could understand.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer

Gradient is smooth shift from one color to another color .

While creating gradient you specify start point , end point and color you want to add .

In below example suppose you create linear gradient start from (0,0) to (170,0).

Then `grad.addColorStop(0,'#0000FF')` starts from beginning  and if your next statement is  `grad.addColorStop(.2,'#00FF00')` . First color ends at 0.2 % of gradient width ( 0.2% of 170) and next color will start from 0.2 % of gradient width.

By saying `addColorStop` you are explicitly saying to stop point of previous color .

Check This [example](http://jsbin.com/lowikomicu/edit?html,js,output) where gradient is same but based on shape position color is different .

```
// Create Gradient 
var grad=context.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);

// Start at 0 end at 0.2
grad.addColorStop(0,'#0000FF');

// Start at 0.2 end at 0.4
grad.addColorStop(.2,'#00FF00');

// Start at 0.4 end at 0.6
grad.addColorStop(.4,'#FFFF00');

// Start at 0.6 end at 0.8
grad.addColorStop(.6,'#FF8800');

// Start at 0.8 end at 0.9
grad.addColorStop(.8,'#FF0000');

//Start at 0.9 to rest all till end
grad.addColorStop(0.9,'white');
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var grad=context.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);

grad.addColorStop(0,'#0000FF');

grad.addColorStop(.2,'#00FF00');

grad.addColorStop(.4,'#FFFF00');

grad.addColorStop(.6,'#FF8800');

grad.addColorStop(.8,'#FF0000');

grad.addColorStop(0.9,'white');

grad.addColorStop(1,'blue');

context.fillStyle = grad;


context.fillRect(0,0,170,100);
context.strokeRect(0,0,170,100)

context.fillRect(80,200,300,100);
context.strokeRect(80,200,300,100)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In grad.addColorStop(), What does the first parameter mean? The number between 0 and 1, what does it signify?,  I don't get that part.

Comment: Its specifies which part you want to pick from gradient . Like If you say  0 , 0.2,0.5 it is calculated like     0 to 0.2 % of Gradient  and 0.2 to 0.3 % of Gradient . Suppose Gradient width is 100 then 0-20 whatever color in gradient will be picked.